# how to use prev to get the value of an input field

Tags: jquery

I have an hidden input field with a value,

```
   <form>
        <input type="hidden" value="product"/>
        <select class="select" name="select3" id="select3">
          <option>0</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
        </select>
  </form>
```

I need to get the value of input field once a button is clicked but I only get the text object why is that?

```
      var items[]; 
      $('#my-add-button-sides').click(function() {
     $('.select option:selected').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        items.push($this.prev($('input[type=hidden]').val ()          
             ));


});
```

thanks

Comment: If you copy and pasted, it might be that the () has a space between it and val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typos in your code. Check if this will help. I fixed array initialization and `prev` call.

```
var items = []; 
$('#my-add-button-sides').click(function() {
    $('.select option:selected').each(function() {
         items.push($(this).parent().prev('input:hidden').val())
     ));
});
```

Comment: Why the each when only one option can be selected. Also prev of an option in a select will either be an other option or nothing (if at first option element)

Comment: That's not true. IF you have more then one select box then this will match all selected options from all of them. Also if you have a multi-select this will return more then one item.

Comment: The example showed 1 select, and it was not multi choice. The prev was still incorrect.

Comment: @redsquare: I fixed problem with prev soon after you pointed it out. About `each`: my goal was to make to code as generic as possible. Sorry that you see it as a bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to get the value of whatever was selected? If so, I don't believe the each() function is necessary. You can simply get the value of the select like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $('#select3').change(function() { 
      var selValue = $(this).val(); 
      alert(selValue); 
  }); 


});


<form name="someForm"> 

    <input type="hidden" value="product"/> 

    <select class="select" name="select3" id="select3"> 

      <option value="0">0</option> 

      <option value="1">1</option> 

      <option value="2">2</option> 

    </select> 

</form>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ipado

Comment: I think he needs a value of a hidden `input` that is before `select` element.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, `this` isn't the select-element, but an option-element. So the hidden input and `this` aren't siblings, and `prev` does not match the element you want.

```
$(this).parent().prev('input:hidden').val()
```

Jump one level up in the DOM, and you'll find the hidden input.